# DataGrid.RowStyle only works on initial binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid, datatrigger

I have a DataTrigger applying a style to the Visibility property of a DataGrid row. The DataTrigger is working just fine on the initial binding of the DataGrid (ie - it sets the row visibility to collapsed if *FilteredOut* is true).

I have a ComboBox that sets the *FilteredOut* property to true or false for each item in the ObservableCollection *AllPartMalfunctions* depending upon what the user has selected in the ComboBox.

Here is my problem: after selecting an item in the ComboBox and setting the *FilteredOut* property for each item, **the DataGrid rows do not refresh to be visible or collapsed** and everything on the UI looks the same as it did before selecting anything in the ComboBox. What am I missing?

Here is the XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding AllPartMalfunctions}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="Auto">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FilteredOut, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FilteredOut, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <!--removed for brevity-->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is the ViewModel to which the DataGrid is binding:

```
public class Malfunctions : ViewModelBase {
       public ObservableCollection<Model.PartMalfunction> AllPartMalfunctions {
            get;
            private set;
        }
}
```

Here is the PartMalfunction Model:

```
public class PartMalfunction {
    private bool _filteredOut = false;
    public bool FilteredOut {
            get {
                return _filteredOut;
            }
            set {
                _filteredOut = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class "PartMalfucntion" needs to implement System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged and fire off the PropertyChanged event when FilteredOut's value is changed.

```
public class PartMalfunction : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    private bool _filteredOut = false;
    public bool FilteredOut
    {
        get {
            return _filteredOut;
        }
        set {
            _filteredOut = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("FilteredOut"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. WPF is becoming less of a mystery to me daily, due to helpful answers like this. Thanks a lot, JH!!